# How to use Outlook OData in SAP WebIDE and HCP?

Tags: azure, microdata, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I recently found the [OData destination of the outlook](https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata). Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started).

I want to use this OData version 4 inside the SAP WebIDE, but for creating the destination in Hana Cloud Platform I have some difficulties and I think I configured something wrong.

[image: Destination for Outlook in SAP HCP]

I registered my app in Azur and got a [ClientID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#BKMK_Native).

I made a destination also by creating a SSL certificate, but when I want to create my application in the WebIDE it does not show the list of the sets.

[image: WebIDE app creation wizard]

Actually the object collection will be empty.

How can I get the list of the sets in this step?